# How to Copy table to (database.table) automatically to another database table in phymyadmin?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

web hosting service does not allow user to synchronize or replicate database in shared web hosting. The only way to copy the database table is using the operation tab "Copy table to (database.table)" .

Example
consider two database , db1 and db2 with table content1 and content2 respectively.

Now how to copy the content1 table from db1 to content2 table from db2.

This can be done in phypmyadmin on operation Copy table to (database.table) but My question is how to do it automatically in phpmyadmin.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have a look [here](https://vijaymrami.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/how-to-schedule-mysql-query-using-mysql-event-in-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a tool for administrators to use to interact with their database installations, so it's not a good tool for scripting a solution. As @Takarii mentions, you may be able to set up a scheduled task to run on schedule to do this. You might be able to write your own small PHP script that would run the copy, and call that on schedule from your own machine, which wouldn't be ideal but doesn't rely on having permissions to run scheduled MySQL tasks. But regardless, phpMyAdmin isn't a good tool to use for this problem.